# Windows Phone Microphone Null Reference Error

Tags: c#, xaml, xna, windows-phone

I have the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        Microphone microphone = Microphone.Default;

        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            microphone =  Microphone.Default;
            microphone.BufferReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferReady);
```

But while running the debugger will break on the last line with a `System.NullReferenceException` error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your `WMAppManifest` file and enable the `ID_CAP_MICROPHONE` capability.

Not related to the issue, but you're unnecessarily setting the `microphone` variable twice.

Comment: That did it! I had no idea about the permissions settings till now! Thanks!